# How can Protagonist understand the lines spoken by inverted Sator in this scene?

Tags: tenet

Protagonist can understand the lines spoken by inverted Sator in this scene:

[image]

Other end of the glass in inverted Sator. How can Protagonist understand the lines spoken by inverted Sator in this scene?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inverted Sator is using his phone to playback his questions in reverse so that the Protagonist can understand him.

We see him playback the recording "before" speaking the question into his phone.

Sator is also playing back the Protagonist's responses and recording them.